# Primefaces - AjaxStatus - Dialog is behind the overlay

Tags: ajax, dialog, primefaces, overlay

[image]

I checked the z-index, but the Dialog z-index is higher than the div of overlay. It was to be correct.

In the showcase works correctly.

Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `<p:dialog`?

Comment: FYI: z-index is relevant only in its stacking context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set `appendToBody = true` and your problem will go away - but be careful to have a form inside if you do some server-side processing. More info when you post more info!

Comment: Very nice spauny. Solved my problem! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had forgotten. Thanks more one time!

Comment: I have the same problem, but I cannot use appendToBody="true", because the page containing the dialog can be loaded several times during session and each time it's loaded a new dialog with the same id is appended to the body. I still do not understand why the overlay happens, can I fix it using css?

Comment: @RahimMammadlee What do you mean? Why is it loaded multiple times? You can update only the output every time instead of updating the whole dialog. Post another question with your entire code and send me the link here, maybe I can help

Comment: Fixed it, the problem was that I didn't fully understand how z-index works. Explained very well here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: In following other post @sleske explains why appending to body might not be a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/33825528/5404186

Comment: I had the same issue with PrimeNg's p-confirmDialog and p-dialog

Answer (score 15):

For primefaces 5.1 you can use appendTo="@(body)"