# Primefaces's dialog 'appendTo' property, what it useful for?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Maybe it's a dumb question, but in Primefaces's `<p:dialog>` there's property which called `appendTo` which described in manual as:

> Appends the dialog to the element defined by the given search
>   expression.

I can't realize what it useful for?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) (currently p. 185):

> Do not place dialog inside tables, containers likes divs with relative positioning or with nonvisible
>   overflow defined, in cases like these functionality might be broken. This is not a limitation
>   but a result of DOM model. For example dialog inside a layout unit, tabview, accordion are a
>   couple of examples. Same applies to confirmDialog as well.

You can overcome this by using `appendTo="@(body)"` and your `dialog` will be attached as a child of the `<body>` node.

One of the main `dialog` option is `modal` and you could quickly end up with your dialog behind the overlay if you are not using `appendTo` as shown below:

[image]

See also http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16504

---

**Notes:**

- Before PrimeFaces 5.0, the attribute to set was `appendToBody="true"`. This was changed for 5.0.
- If your `dialog` contains some buttons don't forget to surround them by `<h:form>` (see [Proper Construct for Primefaces Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579230/proper-construct-for-primefaces-dialog))

Comment: Actually you say that I can place my `<p:dialog>` elsewhere but if it's located inside some another components I should use `appendTo` to avoid problems? If I place it's inside separate form (not nested of course) and it's next child to `<h:body>` I don't really need it. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: `This is not a limitation but a result of DOM model.` - funny how they phrase it. It is a limitation of PF - there is nothing technically preventing them from correctly positioning a dialog inside an absolutely positioned container like a layout unit. They just didn't implement it that way. Of course a dialog could get clipped by the container's boundaries with `overflow: hidden` etc, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 29):

The PrimeFaces docs are a bit sparse on this point. `appendToBody` / `appendTo` (before 5.0) solves (or tries to solve) a problem where a PrimeFaces component does not get the right z-Index, meaning it does not appear before or behind other elements the way it should. However, this feature is problematic because it can cause other problems like [p:commandbutton action doesn't work inside p:dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958729/pcommandbutton-action-doesnt-work-inside-pdialog/)

**tl;dr:**

**Do not use `appendTo` / `appendToBody`. Instead, Dialogs (along with ConfirmDialog and OverlayPanel) should always be at the root of the component hierarchy, as a direct descendant of `<h:body>`. This will make them work reliably. In that case using `appendTo` / `appendToBody` is unnecessary.**

One good way to accomplish this is to have one (or multiple) separate XHTML files for these components ("dialogs.xhtml"), which then gets included in your main XHTML file or template (for example using  `<ui:include>`). Another solution is to use a `<ui:define>` in combination with a `<ui:insert>` if you want the dialogs to remain in the XHTML file where they are used.

Read on for details :-)

---

### The problem

Some PrimeFaces components (such as dialogs) should be be displayed on top of other elements.

For example:

If you use `<p:dialog ...modal="true">`, and make the dialog visible, you get a dialog in the foreground, appearing above the rest of the page, with the rest of the page covered by a transparent layer.
You can see this for example in the [PF Showcase for dialogs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml) (button "Modal").

Behind the scenes, i.e. in the page's DOM, two things happen:

- a new `<div>` (the "modal overlay") is created at the end of the `<body>`. This div gets the CSS styles: `z-index: 1000; position: absolute; opacity: .30;`. This makes it transparent and covering the whole page, to get the "modal" effect.
- the (existing, but invisible) div of the dialog itself is made visible, and gets the styling `z-index: 1001; position:fixed;`. Note the z-index is one larger than the modal overlay, thus the dialog appears above the overlay.

**However**, this does not always work. The reason for this is an aspect of CSS called the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). The details are a bit complex, but basically it says that the z-index of a page element is only compared to other elements inside the same parent element. In particular, an element may appear behind another element even though it has a higher z-index, *if the element with the high z-index is contained in an element with a lower z-index*.

The short (safe) version is: To be certain that z-index works as expected, *all concerned elements should be siblings in the DOM*.

Now, in this particular situation, the modal overlay must be right at the top of the DOM hierarchy (i.e. inside `<body>`), otherwise it cannot reliably appear above the rest of the page. However, the div of the dialog itself is somewhere deeper in the DOM (corresponding to the position of the `<p:dialog>` tag in the source XHTML). **Now we have a problem.**

In practice, this means that the overlay may appear above the dialog, thus obscuring and blocking it. Similarly, if the dialog is not modal, it may appear behind other elements in the page.

The insidious thing about this problem is that it depends on the structure of the rest of the page (specifically, whether the rest of the page uses CSS that creates a new stacking context). So `<p:dialog>` may appear to work initially, then suddenly shows incorrectly after a change elsewhere.

### How 'appendTo' helps

As explained above, the problem occurs because the HTML rendered for the PrimeFaces component is somewhere deep down in the DOM, while it would need to be a direct child of `<body>` for the z-index to work correctly.

When `appendToBody` / `appendTo` is used, PrimeFaces will include Javascript in the rendered page which simply *moves the DOM node of the PrimeFaces component to the end of `<body>`* (using JQuery's [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) function). That way the component is in the right place in the DOM, and z-index works.

### The problem with using 'appendTo'

While the DOM reorganization performed by  `appendTo` solves the problem with CSS and z-index, it introduces another (potential) problem:

**The client-side DOM no longer corresponds to the server-side page state maintained by JSF (called the *view*).**

Now, one of the central features of JSF is that it expects the client-side HTML/DOM structure to correspond to the the server-side view - after all, JSF constructed the HTML from that view. If that rule is violated (usually by manipulating the DOM client-side), you get all kinds of weird problems, such as JSF ignoring form fields or values in a submit, or overwriting part of your modifications on AJAX updates.

In this case, the problems caused by moving the DOM node of the PrimeFaces component include:

- If the PrimeFaces component is part of a `<h:form>`, it will not work properly (because it will not be inside the `<form>` tag client-side because of the moving).
  This is actually mentioned in the PrimeFaces docs, along with the workaround: Instead of putting the component into a form, put a form *inside* the component - then the form will move with the component.
- If the area where JSF originally rendered the PrimeFaces component is updated using JSF's AJAX feature, JSF will remove area to update from the DOM, then render the component again, as it does not know it was moved elsewhere.
  In old versions of PrimeFaces, this caused the component to appear in the DOM twice (with the same `id`), which caused problems with later submits. This was fixed for PrimeFaces 4.0 ( [Issue 5636: Dialog appendToBody & dynamic doesn't remove the old dom element](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5636) ), but re-occurred in 5.0 ([issue #367](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/367)).

This shows that this kind of DOM manipulation "behind JSF's back" is rather risky and should be avoided - thus my advice to not use `appendTo` / `appendToBody`.

Comment: Great detailed analysis. Compliments. I tend to disagree however with your proposed solution (or enhance it if it was just meant as one of the possible solutions). I'd create a `<ui:insert name="dialog"/>` before the closing `</body>` in the template and use a `<ui:define name="dialog>… </ui:define>` in which I'd define the dialogs of that page. That way you keep the dialog with the page

Comment: @Kukeltje: Yes, that is also a nice solution. That's why I wrote "One good way...". I just wanted to give a simple example, which works even for a project that does not use templates. If you use templates, you hopefully know what to do :-).