# primefaces dialog inside another dialog set modal true

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

In my project I use dialog inside another dialog box that both dialog I set **modal=true** that situation click to open dialog box it will open button any action is not performed when I **remove modal=true** in **test2** it will work fine.I use modal in test it not fine.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="test1" modal="true"..>
...
<p:commandButton action="#{user.Button1}" oncomplete="PF('test2').show()"/>
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog widgetVar="test2" modal="true"..>
...
<p:commandButton action="#{user.Button2}" oncomplete="PF('test3').show()"/>
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog widgetVar="test3" modal="true"..>
...

</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

in second put modal = false . it will work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the appendTo?

```
appendTo="..."
```

And check this: [Primefaces's dialog 'appendTo' property, what it useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206643/primefacess-dialog-appendto-property-what-it-useful-for)

It worked for me.