# How to make the dialog set to front

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

Hi guys  I try make a dialog  but when I try to show up, the dialog like this [the dialog stay on back of background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpBow.jpg)

how to make the dialog set to front ?
 but when the dialog already set on the front I want the background still fade or like that

this the code

```
    <p:remoteCommand name="processBack"
                    action="/prpk_paperless/prpk_new.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
                </p:remoteCommand>
                <p:remoteCommand name="processSubmit"
                    action="#{pRPKNonBean.saveEdit}" update="@form">
                </p:remoteCommand>

                <!-- <p:dialog modal="false" widgetVar="successDialog" header="Info"
                    closable="false">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Save data berhasil" />
                        <center>
                            <p:commandButton value="Ok"
                                action="/prpk_paperless/master_prpk.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
                                onclick="PF('successDialog').hide()" immediate="true"/>
                        </center>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog> -->

                <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="successDialog" header="Info"
                    closable="false" >
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Save data berhasil" />
                        <center>
                            <p:commandButton value="Ok" action="/prpk_paperless/master_prpk.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
                                onclick="PF('successDialog').hide()" immediate="true" />
                        </center>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>

                <p:dialog modal="false" widgetVar="failedDialog" header="Info"
                    closable="false">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Save data failed" />
                        <center>
                            <p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#"
                                onclick="PF('failedDialog').hide()" />
                        </center>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>

            </h:form>
                <!-- <p:commandButton value="Back" style="position: relative;"
                    action="/prpk_paperless/prpk_new.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" icon="ui-icon-circle-close"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="processSubmit();"
                    style="float:right; position: relative;" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" /> -->
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="50">

                <p:commandButton value="Back" style="position: relative;"
                    action="/prpk_paperless/prpk_new.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" icon="ui-icon-circle-close"/>

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" onclick="processSubmit();"
                    style="float:right; position: relative;" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" />

        </p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: Most likely because you use a modal=true in a layout without using the appendTo attribute. See the PF docs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434639/primefaces-ajaxstatus-dialog-is-behind-the-overlay

Comment: it's work thanks bro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces - AjaxStatus - Dialog is behind the overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434639/primefaces-ajaxstatus-dialog-is-behind-the-overlay)